# SQL Server Stored Procedure with Float Parameter and passing a decimal

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, floating-point, decimal

I am trying to create a stored procedure that I would call with two table names and a decimal.

If it matters, my stored procedure will compare the # of rows in each table to see if the % difference. If the difference is is greater than the threshold then it will empty one table and copy the data from the other one.

I am able to create the stored procedure, but when I try to call it I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '/'

Code for my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test 
    @table_name_one NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @table_name_two NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @threshhold FLOAT(53)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @table_name_one
END
GO

EXEC test @table_name_one = 'a', @table_name_two = 'b', @threshhold = 1./3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a variable and pass the variable in as below. You can't calculate something while passing it to a parameter.

```
DECLARE @th FLOAT = 1.0 / 3;

EXEC test
    @table_name_one = 'a'
    , @table_name_two = 'b'
    , @threshhold = @th;
```

Comment: No. There may be some exception I cannot think of off the top of my head, but typically you want to pass in parameters as: execute [<schema>].[<proc>] @p1='value', @p2=@variable...etc.